# Will FIRAuth.addAuthStateDidChangeListener wait until the end of the initialization before calling the listener?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The documentation of Firebase Auth for iOS regarding the [`addAuthStateDidChangeListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-addauthstatedidchangelistener) function states:

> Registers a block as an "auth state did change" listener. To be invoked when:
>
> - The block is registered as a listener,
> - A user with a different UID from the current user has signed in, or
> - The current user has signed out.
>
> The block is invoked immediately after adding it according to it’s standard invocation semantics, asynchronously on the main thread.

The first point above and the last paragraph confuse me. If I add a listener immediately after having initialized Firebase, is it possible for the listener to be called before Firebase Auth have restored the user from a previous session?

In such case, how can I distinguish if the call of the listener with a null user occurs because there is no user or because the user has not been restored yet?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible for the auth state listener to be called before the authentication state has been restored, in which case the listener will be called with a "user is not signed in" state initially, before being called with a "user is signed in".

The Android SDK these days actually hides that first auth state, but I don't think the iOS SDK does the same. You might want to give it a try though. Simple sign in to the app, close the app, wait for at least an hour (so that your access token has expired) and start the app again.

I'm not sure how most developers handle this, but I know of these two ways:

1. Make the redirect to the sign-in page explicit. So if you get an auth state without a user, show a link to the sign-in page. In the scenario with the initial "not signed in" that means the user will see this page for a moment, until the sign-in state is restored.
2. Make the redirect wait for the refresh. This is essentially just a time-out with something like "detecting sign-in state" or something similar. You might want to include a explicit redirect link in there too, for users who know they won't be signed in.

I agree that neither if these is ideal in a mobile app, so I am curious to see what others do.

Comment: Hi Frank, I stumbled into this thread and the behavior you’re describing might explain why we have users who occasionally get logged out. Do you know if iOS is still behaving differently form Android today? Why isn’t this behavior documented?